# How to add Mic button on touchbar on Macbook pro 13"

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, touch-bar

I have a sound button on touchbar, however there's no mic mute / unmute button on the same. Is there any way to customize the same to add new control? It will be very helpful during online meetings. Specially when working in multi-window environment.